# What does "Transaction address table lookup uses an invalid index" mean?

Tags: web3.js

What does this error mean? I have been looking everywhere and can't figure out what the issue is. Below is the code snippet of how I'm using the Address Lookup Table. I know this feature is under-development/newly released. But in general, there's barely any documentation out there regarding the Address Lookup Tables. :(

```
const lookupTableResponse = await connection.getAddressLookupTable(
    lookupTableKey,{
      commitment: 'processed',
    },
  );
const lookupTableAccount = lookupTableResponse.value;

const message = MessageV0.compile({
    instructions: instructions,
    payerKey: myWallet.publicKey,
    recentBlockhash: blockhash,
    addressLookupTableAccounts: [lookupTableAccount],
  });

// Assume I've attained all signatures
const versionedTx = new VersionedTransaction(message, signatures);

await connection.sendRawTransaction(versionedTx.serialize(), {preflightCommitment: 'confirmed'});
```

Comment: What version of the `@solana/web3.js` package are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.59.0

Comment: I tried running your code on my end, and did not get any errors. Is the message "Transaction address table lookup uses an invalid index" the exact message you are getting?

Comment: It's quite inconsistent. Sometimes I get "Transaction signature invalid" message (I forget the exact message but it's about wrong signature). But most of the time, I get the EXACT message "Transaction address table lookup uses an invalid index". I can try again. Btw i'm running against devnet not sure if that matters.

Comment: Being on devnet should not matter. Can you share more of your code snippet in your question to help further troubleshoot/debug? How are you getting your 'signatures'? The way the `VersionedTransaction` function works is different than the older `Transaction` function. Transaction allows you to pass an array of `Keypair`  as your second param, however `VersionedTransaction` does not. You will need to get the full signatures or use the `VersionedTransaction().sign([payer, anotherWallet, etc])` function

Answer (score 4):

Had this same issue. In my case, it was because the lookup table was still activating. Immediately after creating the lookup table, I then created a transaction using the lookup table. Introducing a wait before executing any lut transactions should solve your problem.

Generally, the error can be linked to here:

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/3608801a54600431720b37b53d7dbf88de4ead24/programs/address-lookup-table/src/state.rs#L177

You can see this will get thrown if the table isn't yet active. It would also get thrown if web3.js compiled your message incorrectly, referencing keys that didn't exist. But I doubt it's easy for that to happen.